# Tube adhering to tire

Tags: maintenance, puncture

I was fixing a flat this morning and discovered that the tube was adhering to the tire casing. The tube pulled free from the tire, with about as much force as it would take to pull off well adhered (but not "baked on") masking tape.

I don't think I've ever encountered this before and I'm wondering if it is indicative of a problem?

Comment: Of course, if the tube has ever been patched, the patch area is far more likely to stick to the inside of the tire.

Comment: This one was getting its first patch… It was sticking very evenly all around the tire. Made me wonder there were incompatibilities between some tires and tubes. Also, there was very little evidence of any talc (no white powder).

Comment: It used to be that new tubes were pre-dusted with talc, but of course they've stopped doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tubes sticking to tires are pretty normal and not a problem, especially if the tube has been in the tire for a long time. Some people put talc or whatever in a tire to avoid this, but its not necessary.

Comment: Talc can have an additional benefit of allowing the tube and tire to move independently which helps in prevention of some types of flats--notably pinch flats. Thus, talc or something similar can enable use of lower pressures.

Comment: That's an [urban legend](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/talcum.html).

Comment: Perhaps, or so says jobst brandt. His rationale applies in high pressure situations, but not in lower pressures like cx or MTB.